# XSLT order in months AND years

Tags: xslt, foreach, slice, foreach-loop-container

I have a problem. I have an XML tree which looks similar to this:

```
<wd:meta>
    <wd:creation time="[TIMESTAMP]" />
    <wd:title><![CDATA[Nice title]]></wd:title>
</wd:meta>
```

And there are many more siblings with the same Structure.
This tree goes into the XSLTProcessor and gets a nice Stylesheet.
Now i want to take this apart into months (In my Stylesheet). So that there is something like that:

> Everything that happed in August
>
> > Nice title 1
> >
> > Nice title 2
>
> Everything that happend in September
>
> > Nice title 3
> >
> > Nice title 4

How can i do something like this? I made a little bit of research but i wasn't very successful.
The only thing i found what would be maybe useful was that: following-sibling

Can anyone help me? I really appreciate your help.

Thanks.

---

edit://

I now used the Muenchian method adopted from http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html but i only can order it by month, NOT by year. I tried the Answer of the possible duplicate and tried to understand it, but it's not that easy. Has anyone a easier solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XSLT, sort and group by year-date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770383/xslt-sort-and-group-by-year-date)

Comment: Thanks. Yes i think it's the same problem. My research was not this good -.- But the answer there is too high for me anyway. I am a real beginner.

Answer (score 0):

In a first step i would iterate your content and generate a monthname for your timestamps. Then you can sort it by the month name. If you have xslt 2.0 you can use `group-by` to group them by month. If not, you can acturlly iterate your content and check if there is a `following-sibling` with the current month name. If so, go on with the same month name as the month of the current element. If not, start a new month.

Comment: thank you, i will try to add a new attribute where i will save the month. And i look if i can do this with your advice.