# How to group / sort records by value of some inner attribute?

Tags: list, xslt, grouping

I wonder if there's way (actually I tried to find myself but hasn't been successful at all) how to re-sort XML report of records according to some group chracteristics. Let's say I have log file consisting of records in form of

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<log>
  <record id="12345">
    <author>me</author>
    <ts>2014-05-02T13:03:50.528995Z</ts>
    <data>arbitrary data</data>
  </record>
  <record id="23456">
    <author>someone else</author>
    <ts>2014-05-05T08:24:32.123495Z</ts>
    <data>another arbitrary data</data>
  </record>
  …
</log>
```

What I want is to group records by author in a report: author's name and below ordered list of particular records. I don't know in advance who authors are, so I need to create list of their names dynamically.

Is XSLT capable of solving of this?

Comment: This is a frequently asked question. Do a search. Or try one of the "related" topics shown.

Comment: OK, you are right. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770383/xslt-sort-and-group-by-year-date also known as two-phase Muenchian grouping is exactly what I've been looking for. I don't get why I didn't see it before in search results but thanks, anyway.

Comment: If you're only grouping by author, then a "one-phase" Muenchian grouping should be sufficient - but Muenchian grouping is definitely the answer, if you're using XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so after carefully reading [Jeni Tennison's](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) tutorial I've figured it out.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0">

  <xsl:key name="key-authors" match="record" use="author" />

  <xsl:template match="log">

    <xsl:for-each select="record[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kAuthors',author)[1])]">
      <xsl:sort select="./author" />
      <xsl:value-of select="./author" />

      <xsl:for-each select="key('kAuthors',./author)">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
      </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:for-each>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="record">
    <!-- do whatever with the record values: @id, author, ts, data -->
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks, michael.hor257k.